# Свернуть блоки кода в VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

Подскажите, как свернуть отдельные блоки кода (теги) в VS CODE? Стрелки для сворачивания нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нажмите `Ctrl` + `,`.
В строке поиска вбейте `Show Folding Controls`.
Установите значение `always`.

Comment: Ура! Спасибо! Помогло!!!

Answer (score 0):

Также возможно настроить через settings.json(пользовательские настройки)

```
"editor.folding": true,
```